# Get request works in R, but not in Python (certificate verify failed error)

Tags: python, web-scraping, request

I usually do web scraping in R, but now I have to do it in python. I stacked on the first step. In r, normal GET request work as usual:

```
library(rvest)
p <- read_html("https://www.belex.rs/")
```

In python, I got error:

```
import requests
hdrs = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla / 5.0 (X11 Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit / 537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome / 52.0.2743.116 Safari / 537.36'}
p = requests.get("https://www.belex.rs/", allow_redirects=True, headers=hdrs)

"...requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.belex.rs', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')])")))"
```

Why GET request works in R, but doesn't work in python and what to do to make it work (I know there is verify=False option, but I read it is not recommended due to security issues in production)?